# What's the name of the set including this piece? Red Technic and system pincer?

Tags: sets, set-identification

[image]

This piece is a pair of claws/tweezers the I don't know the name of, it's part of the set and might help.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like that's [Exo-Force set 7701-1, Grand Titan](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7701-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).

[image]